# SQL and VB - How to apply a function to test if the copy is in spanish

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I have a function that I would like to apply to my SQl query. I am using SQL Server.

I can't think of a good way to do it though. Basically i want to be able to check the column COPY  to see if it's Spanish
I imagine something like this

Select * from INFO where isForeign(Copy)

Here is the function:

```
Function IsForeign(theString)
   Dim strAlphaNumeric
   Dim strChar
   Dim Found
   Dim i

   strAlphaNumeric = "àáâèéçêóô"                                                                   ' French, Spanish
   strAlphaNumeric = strAlphaNumeric & "ÀÈÉÒÓÙàèéòóù"                   ' Italian

   strChar = ""
   Found = False

   ' Characters
   For i = 1 to Len(theString)
          strChar = Mid(theString, i, 1)
          If Instr(strAlphaNumeric, strChar) Then
                 Found = True
          End If
   Next


   IsForeign = Found
```

End Function

Comment: You should add the information which DBMS you are using. That might be important.

Comment: I would be hard pressed trying to write something like this myself and start [here](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/)

Comment: I am using SQL Server.... i just thought of somthing- think i will use:

Comment: i just thought of somthing- think i will somehow incorporate: Select * from where Patindex('%[list of accent vowels]%'),copy) > 0

Comment: I fully agree with the statement above that this is something too difficult to do from scratch. The whole point of this comment is saying that I have found particularly curious one of the words you chose to know whether a text is in Spanish: "contrarrestar" (counteract). It seems like an extremely accurate system to know if a text is in Spanish, although its reliability would most likely be pretty low (not too probable to get a text with this word) :)

Comment: Serious now: you cannot take the accented vowels as a reference as far as exist in other languages (also most of non-Spanish IT systems do not recognise them and thus people tend to omit accents in some contexts). "un" might also be misunderstood (present in French, for example). What it would surely define Spanish is letter "ñ" (although it might not be present in the text either).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this function depends on the input data.

If the input data is either English or Spanish, then using a subset of common Spanish words and non-standard English characters would probably give a high degree of confidence.

However, if the input data could be other languages, Portuguese, Italian, French, etc, then this would give a low degree of accuracy. In that case, perhaps a dictionary check against all the words in your dataset would give a better result.  Of course, for that method you have to check all the accepted languages for the whole string, so hardly efficient.

Perhaps some kind of Bayesian analysis, or Predictive Analysis would deliver results.

Of course, 100% accuracy is likely to be unachievable within the scope of this site.